# What is the proper way to designate the data context and bind hierarchical data in the treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a fairly simple data model:

```
public class ServiceModel
{
    private static readonly IQmiServiceManager ServiceManager = Bootstrap.Instance.DomainManager.QmiServiceManager;

    private string _serviceName;
    private ObservableCollection<string> _serviceMessages;


    public string Name
    {
        get { return _serviceName; }
        private set { _serviceName = value.ToUpper(); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages
    {
        get { return _serviceMessages; }
        private set { _serviceMessages = value; }
    }


    public ServiceModel(string ServiceName, IList<string> ServiceMessages)
    {
        Name = ServiceName;
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<string>(ServiceMessages);
    }

}
```

...which is encapsulated in this view model:

```
public class ServiceCollectionViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<ServiceModel> _serviceModels = new ObservableCollection<ServiceModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceModel> ServiceModels
    {
        get { return _serviceModels; }
    }

}
```

I have the following treeview xaml definition:

```
<TreeView Name="ServiceTree" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Messages}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Nothing is being output in the tree. I have tried following several tutorials on hierarchical data-binding but I'm simply having difficulty understanding the proper technique for my specific situation.

Also, how should the data-context be set? I am setting the context as follows within the code-behind of the view:

```
public partial class ServiceView : UserControl
{

    private readonly ServiceCollectionViewModel _serviceCollection = new ServiceCollectionViewModel();

    public ObservableCollection<ServiceModel> Services
    {
        get { return _serviceCollection.ServiceModels; }
    }

    public ServiceView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = _serviceCollection;
        _serviceCollection.LoadServices();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be very confused. You're trying to data bind to your `ServiceView.Services` property, so what is the `ServiceCollectionViewModel` class for? The sole purpose of a view model is to provide *all of the data (and functionality) required for its view*.

Now we can go different routes... it all depends what you actually want. If you want to data bind from outside the `UserControl` to the `ServiceView.Services` property, then you must declare the `Services` property as a `DependencyProperty`. Inside your `UserControl`, you would then data bind to the property using a `RelativeSource Binding` like this:

Outside:

```
<YourPrefix:ServiceView Services="{Binding YourExternalViewModelProperty}" />
```

Inside:

```
<TreeView Name="ServiceTree" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Services, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:ServiceView}}}">
    ...
</TreeView>
```

With this method, there is no need to set the `DataContext` to anything as we are using `RelativeSource` to set the data source. Alternatively, you could set the `DataContext` to either the internal `UserControl` code behind, or an instance of a view model (from either inside or outside) and then normally data bind like this:

```
<TreeView Name="ServiceTree" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Services}">
    ...
</TreeView>
```

So, to recap, if you set the `DataContext` to an instance of an object, then your `Binding Path`s look at the properties in that object to resolve themselves. Otherwise, if you set a `RelativeSource` (or `ElementName`) in your `Binding Path`, then you are changing the data source *for that `Binding` only* and your `Binding Path`s should be properties from those objects instead.

---

UPDATE >>>

The [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) is basically a slight extension on the regular old `DataTemplate` class and can be thought of a `DataTemplate` with an `ItemsSource` property. Therefore, if you can define the content of a `DataTemplate`, then you can define the content of a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`... just make sure to set the `HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource` property to a valid collection property... in your case, the `Messages` property:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourPrefix:ServiceModel}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}"> <!-- Collection Property In ServiceModel -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" /> <!-- Property In ServiceModel -->
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

If you're not too clear on `DataTemplate`, take a look at the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: And what should the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` look like in the XAML? I follow what you are saying here and choose the *internal* route. I am getting service names but none of the *children* nodes containing messages (`ObservableCollection<string>`) defined in the `ServiceModel`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of issues here.

1. `ItemsSource` binding should be to `ServiceModels` and not `Services`, because that is the name of the property in your `ServiceCollectionViewModel`. SO this way you get the top-level items.
2. You are trying to bind inside your items' style to `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties, but there are no such properties on your view-models.
3. Inside your `HierarchicalDataTemplate` you bind the `ItemsSource` property directly to the `DataContext` of the `TreeViewItem` which in this case is `ServiceModel`. Either make the `ServiceModel` implement `IEnumerable<string>` exposing your messages, or bind to `Messages` property directly:
4. The second level `HierarchicalDataTemplate` binds the `Text` property to `Messages`, but the `DataContext` of this level is of `String` type, having no `Messages` property. So here you should bind to the data context itself:

Regarding the data context, you better initialize it in XAML, using static resource. Also, much cleaner approach to define the hierarchical data templates is using **implicit** templates, based on the item types. Because you really don't want to define hierarchical templates inline for a greater number of hierarchy levels (say: 4, 5). See below the completely fixed XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <!--Data context for the whole Grid-->
        <myNamespace:ServiceCollectionViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TreeView Name="ServiceTree"
              DataContext="{StaticResource MyViewModel}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceModels}">
        <TreeView.Resources>

            <!--Implicit style for TreeViewItem, IsExpanded and IsSelected have no binding because 
            they are not used by view-models-->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <!--Template for the first level items-->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myNamespace:ServiceModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

            <!--Template for the second level, due to the fact that String is not hierarchical
            regular DataTemplate is enough-->
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

I believe this one is both more understandable and, consequently, more maintainable.

Comment: add to xaml declarations: `xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Comment: I  concentrate in this example on the essence of the proper TreeView declaration, not on providing a full-blown UserControl. Feel free to edit the answer if you think it's necessary.

Comment: After having to move ViewModels and Models to the same project as the Views, I still have nothing showing up in the treeview. Otherwise, thanks for the info, it is still helpful in figuring out some other techniques.

Comment: I used exactly the view-models you shown in your question and it worked. How do you populate the ServiceModels collection? Do you see any warnings/errors in your XAML, Debug output?